# Accessing HTML5 <canvas> from NaCl code

Tags: c++, google-chrome, html5-canvas, google-nativeclient

I'm interested in porting my HTML5 Canvas / JavaScript game to NaCl / C++ but I can't find any good sample source code of NaCl accessing the canvas. Could somebody point me to a few samples? Please note that I'm only interested in the standard 2D canvas, no need for complex 3D / OpenGL stuff. Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at the NaCL site? https://developers.google.com/native-client/sdk/examples

Comment: Yeah, they have no source code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found a pretty good source of code on this matter:
http://gonativeclient.appspot.com/dev/demos/sdk_examples/

Problem solved!

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution to your problem. Be advised that these are examples included in the standard NaCl SDK. They won't be using the HTML5 canvas element; they will be using Chrome's Pepper drawing API for graphics.

Answer (score 6):

NaCL does not use HTML5 APIs, but have its own API subsystem called *Pepper*.

It has Graphics2D class which is one you are probably looking for:

https://developers.google.com/native-client/peppercpp/classpp_1_1_graphics2_d

As far as I know NaCL clients don't have access to page elements, but operate within `<embed>` tag sandbox: https://developers.google.com/native-client/devguide/coding/application-structure

The communication with NaCL apps happen over JavaScript `postMessage()` pump https://developers.google.com/native-client/devguide/coding/message-system